# How to write a copyconstructor for a class which has HANDLE as a member in win32 c++ application?

Tags: c++, winapi, copy-constructor

I have a HANDLE as member in my class say it is file handle got using win32 api , how do i handle it in copy constructor, does my class take responsibility of taking care of releasing it?

Answer (score 6):

You're having this problem because you're trying to define a copy constructor for a class that contains an abstract resource (as opposed to a value). You'll have to decide what behavior you actually want from your copy constructor. Perhaps you don't even want the class to be copy-constructible in the first place.

For example, consider you class encapulates an opened read-only file. Then, it would make sense for the copy constructor to call DuplicateHandle (as suggested by Matt), and for the destructor to call CloseHandle. There will be no interference between an original instance and a copied instance, since you won't be writing the file.

On the other hand, if the class represents a temporary file, a different semantic *may* be desired - perhaps it would be useful for the copy constructor to *copy* the entire file, so that a copy of your class will not interfere with the original. Or maybe this behavior feels too implicit, and you decide the class won't have a copy constructor, instead you'll have to explicitly use a copy method.

So, unless you explain what exactly you're doing, and the manner in which you intend to use the class, there is no "right" answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Windows API [DuplicateHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms724251%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the copy constructor if you want the handle to be copied, in this case, you call Closehandle if no longer using the handle.

Answer (score 1):

DuplicateHandle probably makes the most sense here as others have suggested but since a HANDLE is basically a pointer you could also use a std::shared_ptr (or it's boost counterpart) with CloseHandle as the deleter. Then the handle can be copied around as much as you like and will be automatically closed when the last instance of your class is destroyed.

Just beware that the handle is shared so if you modify any of its associated state you change it for all you instances referencing that handle. If that's an issue I would duplicate it or disallow copying entirely.